# Return ResultSet in pgsql function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have the function below...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION class_listing(var_sem integer, var_sy character) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
DECLARE
    current_offering record;

BEGIN
    SELECT subcode, offerno INTO current_offering FROM offering WHERE SY=var_sem AND SEM=var_sy;

END;
```

How to return `current_offering` as resultset?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SQL or PLpgSQL functions. Using anonymous records as returning type is not practical (mainly it is not friendly, when you write queries). Use RETURNS TABLE or OUT parameters instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION class_listing(var_sem integer, var_sy varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (subcode varchar, offerno int) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT o.subcode, o.offerno
                  FROM offering 
                 WHERE SY=var_sem AND SEM=var_sy;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or SQL language

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION class_listing(var_sem integer, var_sy varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (subcode varchar, offerno int) AS $$
  SELECT o.subcode, o.offerno
                  FROM offering 
                 WHERE SY=$1 AND SEM=$2;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Attentions - query based functions works (with small exception) as optimizer barrier. So be careful when you use it in complex queries.

For completeness - your example can be written as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION class_listing(var_sem integer, var_sy varchar)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE current_offering record;
BEGIN
  FOR current_offering IN 
          SELECT o.subcode, o.offerno
             FROM offering 
            WHERE SY=var_sem AND SEM=var_sy;
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT current_offering;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this form is deprecated now